# How to switch from using a stack to just using the parent field in a parse tree?

Tags: python, binary-tree, parse-tree

I have a homework assignment about making a parse tree after taking in a fully-parenthesized string and then printing the parse tree. It asks me to modify a couple things and one of those is to change the way we keep track of the parent node. In the original code they use a stack to do so, but my instructor told us to just use the parent node instead.

I have all the code running in the same file rather than having to deal with imports for now.

These are the rules the algorithm uses to create a parse tree:

- If the current token is a `'('`, add a new node as the left child of the current node, and descend to the left child.
- If the current token is in the list `['+','-', '^', '/','*']`, set the root value of the current node to the operator represented by the current token. Add a new node as the right child of the current node and descend to the right child.
- If the current token is a number, set the root value of the current node to the number and return to the parent.
- If the current token is a `')'`, go to the parent of the current node.

First is creating a binary tree:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        if self.leftChild == None:
            self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = t

    def insertRight(self,newNode):
        if self.rightChild == None:
            self.rightChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.rightChild = self.rightChild
            self.rightChild = t


    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def setRootVal(self,obj):
        self.key = obj

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.key
```

Next is the Stack class which I want to change:

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)
```

After that is the putting the parse tree together(I'll mark things with a '#' that I think I need to change):

```
def buildParseTree(fpexp): #fpexp is a string that we want to create into a parse tree
    fplist = fpexp.split()
    pStack = Stack()           #
    eTree = BinaryTree('')
    pStack.push(eTree)         #
    currentTree = eTree
    for i in fplist:
        if i == '(':
            currentTree.insertLeft('')
            pStack.push(currentTree)      #
            currentTree = currentTree.getLeftChild()
        elif i not in ['+', '-', '^', '*', '/', ')']:
            currentTree.setRootVal(i)
            parent = pStack.pop()          #
            currentTree = parent
        elif i in ['+', '-', '^', '*', '/']:
            currentTree.setRootVal(i)
            currentTree.insertRight('')
            pStack.push(currentTree)     #
            currentTree = currentTree.getRightChild()
        elif i == ')':
            currentTree = pStack.pop()   #
        else:
            raise ValueError
    return eTree
```

Here is the code in pastebin with the print function and expressions I test:
https://pastebin.com/DmdkHuhF